# Doctrine event listener and softdeleted filter

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have entity answers and I use `softdeleted` filter for them, and when I remove entity in some action everything fine, I have deletedAt datetime, but when I try remove this entity in `OnFlushEvent` my entity is gone from DB, why ?

```
 public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $em->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof Questions) {
            $existAnswers = $this->container->get('app.repository.question_answers')
                ->findOneBy(['questions' => $entity]);
                        $em->remove($existAnswers);                                                          
        }
    }
}
```

entity

```
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class QuestionAnswers
```

config service

```
    app.doctrine_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\DoctrineListener
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

I checked, this filter enabled, I try force enable but no helped

Comment: Could you add your listener service definition?

Comment: of course, updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be related to subscribers priority.

In fact seems that also `SoftDeleteableListener` implements a subscriber which collect entities to softdelete using `onFlush()` event as we can see [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/SoftDeleteableListener.php). Therefore if your event is fired after the softdeletable one, your entities will be normally deleted from Doctrine.

To avoid this I would set `priotity` on your subscriber in order to fire your events before `SoftDeleteableListener` ones

```
app.doctrine_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\DoctrineListener
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default, priority: -256 }
```